# Silverlight float content right

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'm trying to get a horizontal StackPanel with some text, and then a button stuck all the way to the right hand side.  I tried this:

```
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="5,0,0,0">Ahoy!</TextBlock>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource buttonGlassOrb}" Background="Red" />
                </StackPanel>
```

Which doesn't seem to work.  Obviously adding a margin to the TextBlock will work, like this:

```
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="5,0,120,0">Ahoy!</TextBlock>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource buttonGlassOrb}" Background="Red" />
                </StackPanel>
```

But that's bad for all sorts of reasons.  Are there any more natural ways to do this?

Comment: As pointed out by several users, the best solution is probably a Grid. Q: What specific "StackPanel" behaviour are you after? That will determine the grid column settings.

Comment: Yeah, I felt really silly after seeing the answer.  I just needed a grid - simple as that.  I'm fairly new to WPF/Silverlight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I would use a Grid instead of a StackPanel for this.  Just add two columns, one set to size "*" and one to "Auto", and put your TextBlock in column one, Button in Column two:

Answer (score 3):

Use a DockPanel instead:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="5,0,0,0">Ahoy!</TextBlock>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="25" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource buttonGlassOrb}" Background="Red" />
</DockPanel>
```

The default Dock setting is Left so it behaves like a Horizontal StackPanel for items that have no explicit Dock setting.

Comment: This ir really the best answer for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

StackPanels are OK for simplistic scenarios, as soon as you want full control on the layout, use Grid